# AJAX | PHP set cookie - cross site

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 websites, on different servers.
website1.com and website2.com

I am trying to set a cookie for website2.com on website1.com using ajax.

run.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
setcookie("cook", "test", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo $_COOKIE["cook"];
```

Error: Undefined index: cook

My cookie is not being set.

When running website2.com/run.php directly this works but not with ajax.

Comment: I believe the page needs to be reloaded before the cookie is actually set and can be accessed through `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: var_dump(setcookie("cook", "test", time() + (86400 * 30), "/")); what is the output ?

Comment: @kunruh not the issue.

Comment: your cookie setted , did you tried to give domain for last parameter ?

Comment: @Onur yes, same issue does not work. could this be because of CORS?

Comment: yes this is another case @richardgrant

Comment: It's not possible for one domain to set a cookie in another domain. It's totally prohibited by HTTP security.